# How to disable cookies with Revive Ad Server

Tags: openx

I am using Revive Ad Server and to comply with EU Law I need to be able to disable the tracking cookies that Revive creates when tracking ads. I have looked everywhere online for a solution but can't find one, how would I prevent Revive creating a cookie if the user opts-out?

Answer (score 0):

It is really easy, For each Zone you could either enable or disable the Cookies.

Go to - From your Revive Ad Server, Select Zones, Then Advanced Tab, Then you see Cookies Selection, Then the setting there.

Comment: This option is not for disabling cookies! The option determines whether to cap ads in case the cookies are disabled (on the client side). See the description of the option:
> Frequency capping depends on the ability to set user cookies.  Selecting this option will allow for delivery of banners to users before it is known if they accept cookies (such as on the first applicable page view), and also allow for unlimited exposure (no frequency capping) to users that do not accept cookies.